# Column identifiers used with NSTableView autosave feature must conform to NSCoding protocol:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have an NSTableView and I am trying to set Autosave to preserve column sizing and sorting.

In the attributes inspector I have entered a value into the "Autosave" field under "Table View" and have checked "Column Information".

When I build and run the app, I get an error:

```
Column identifiers used with NSTableView autosave feature must conform to NSCoding protocol: (null)
```

I am new to Cocoa/Objective-C so it isn't clear to me how I define the column identifiers?

**Update**: I didn't enter any value for the identifier, it is listed as "automatic".  However if I enter a string value into the Identifier for the Table Column I still get the same result

**Update II**: Cleaning and rebuilding seemed to fix it after manually entering values.  But why would automatic identifiers not work?

Comment: What did you enter as the column identifier?

Comment: updated q with response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cleaning and rebuilding seemed to fix it after manually entering
>   values. But why would automatic identifiers not work?

Interface Builder is flaky sometimes about accepting input. They did quite a bit of re-work integrating IB directly into Xcode 4 which added many odd bugs.

Apple has done a decent job of stabilizing IB in Xcode 4 as point releases have come out. The amount of clean/rebuild required is much less than it used to be.

Comment: Cleaning and Rebuilding did not fix of me. And all my column identifiers are not (null). I don't get the message. I'm on Xcode 3

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem until I made sure each column had an identifier.  Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers on this question actually answer the question satisfactorily.  Yes, you need to set an identifier value for each `NSTableColumn`; "automatic" identifiers apparently don't work (as of Xcode 7.2).  But where do you set these?  The identifier is not in the Value Inspector in the IB pane, where you might expect it to be (that's where I looked for it, and then did some head-scratching).  Rather, it is on the Identity Inspector in the IB pane, the one that looks like a little newspaper.  I guess `identifier` is perhaps a general property of all nib objects (?), but I don't recall ever needed to use it before for anything else, so I had never noticed that it was there.  Anyhow, I'm adding this answer in case others are puzzled, as I was, as to where the `identifier` can be set...

Comment: It is located in the third pane of the inspector, along with the class name